# How to disable all IRQs on A53?

Tags: arm64

I have such codes expect to halt cpu on wfi:

```
__asm volatile ( "MSR DAIFSET, #15" );
__asm volatile ( "DSB SY" );
__asm volatile ( "ISB SY" );
__asm volatile ("wfi");
print("never get here\n");
```

The problem is I always get a log "never get here", why this happen?
the irq occured I can guess is arch timer PPI. But shouldn't it be disabled?

platform is cortex-a53 in el3.

I change code to:

```
__asm volatile ( "MSR DAIFSET, #15" );
__asm volatile ( "DSB SY" );
__asm volatile ( "ISB SY" );
while (1) {
    __asm volatile ("wfe");
    print("never get here\n");
}
```

and I got endless "never get here", what is the wake up event source?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`wfi` doesn't work the way you think it does. See the [ARMv8 Reference Manual](https://static.docs.arm.com/ddi0487/da/DDI0487D_a_armv8_arm.pdf), section D1.17.2:

> #### D1.17.2 Wait For Interrupt
>
> [...]
>   The architecture permits a PE to leave the low-power state for any reason, but requires that it must leave the low-power state on receipt of any architected WFI wake-up event.
>
> ---------- Note ----------
>   Because the architecture permits a PE to leave the low-power state for any reason, it is permissible for a PE to treat WFI as a NOP, but this is not recommended for lowest power operation.
>   ----------------------------
>
> [...]
>
> **WFI wake-up events**
>
> The following are WFI wake-up events:
>
> - Any physical SError interrupt, IRQ interrupt, or FIQ interrupt received by the PE, [...] regardless of the value of the corresponding PSTATE.{A, I, F} mask bit.
> - [...]
>
> ---------- Note ----------
>
> - WFI wake-up events are never disabled by EDSCR.INTdis, and are never masked by the PSTATE.{A, I, F} mask bits. If wake-up is invoked by an interrupt that is disabled or masked the interrupt is not taken.
> - [...]
>
> ----------------------------

So your interrupt masking works fine, it's just that `wfi` doesn't care about that and can simply be a `nop` to begin with.

In contrast to that, `wfe` seems to be designed to force entry in a low-power state, and does honour the interrupt masks. I only glanced over it so there might yet be a caveat, but see section G1.18.1 in the manual.

Comment: I tried wfe, still get the "never get here" log. I have two a53 cores, with wfi, core0 will get to "never get here", core1 will stop on wfi. With wfe, both cores get to "never get here".

Comment: That sounds strange... maybe you get `EVENT*` signal inputs? Also, what are you trying to do exactly? Maybe `hlt` (enter debug state) or a crude `b .` (infinite spin) will help you?

Comment: what is EVENT* signal?

Comment: See [this page](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0464e/CJHCHFJE.html).

Comment: I guess it's a problem in print. I have acquire/release spinlock in print function. in the spinlock release, it will use 'stlr' instruction, which create an extra event, which got catched by the WFE.